# ¿Qué es "hacer el pinflas"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, españa

Hace un rato en nuestro chat La Tertulia [dijo blonfu](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41002241#41002241):

> ¿eso es una especie de Meta pero para **hacer el pinflas**?

Por contexto entiendo que se refería a si una cosa en concreto es una especie de sitio Meta de Stack Exchange donde realizar *probatinas*. Sin embargo, me pareció muy curioso -¡y divertido!- el uso de *pinflas*, que nunca había oído. El DLE no lo reconoce, el CREA no tiene ningún resultado al respecto.

La pregunta es: ¿qué quiere decir exactamente *hacer el pinflas*? Además, ¿de dónde viene "pinflas"? En la zona noreste de España yo nunca lo he oído, ¿dónde se usa?

Comment: Por si sirve de algo comento que esta expresión la leí (si no recuerdo mal) allá por los años 90 en una entrevista que les hacían a *Def Con Dos*. En un momento dado uno de los integrantes del grupo decía algo como: "estábamos haciendo el pinflas" que yo  interpreté como hacer el tonto o hacer bobadas o hacer el gamberro. Desde entonces vengo usando esa expresión pero la verdad que nunca la he vuelto a escuchar ni leer en ningún otro sitio.

Comment: @blonfu iba a intentar responder la pregunta buscando la referencia de esta entrevista. Curiosamente, esta pregunta ya es la primera entrada en [google de _hacer el pinflas_](https://www.google.com/search?q=hacer+el+pinflas)

Comment: Lo más cercano que he podido ver es _una pinfla de hostias_ ("una sarta de puñetazos") y _me (la) pinfla tu xxxx_ ("me importa un carajo tu xxxx"), en foros muy informales y antiguos ¿Son expresiones comunes? _Pinflas_ no lo he visto en ningún lado. _Pin flash_ no es buena idea.

Comment: ¿Y "repampinfla" o "refanfinfla"?

Comment: No se si tendrá relación, pero en https://uvejuegos.com/foro-aportacion/De-donde-vendran-o-por-que-se-diran-ciertas-expresiones/1598015/1#1598015 mencionan: "Por donde yo vivo, decirle a uno que es un cantamañanas es decirle "eres un Pink Floyd",  que otro participante corrige "Bueno, más que "Pink Floyd" sería "**pinflói**". "  El **pinflói** se parece algo a **pinflas**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si buscas "el pinflas" en Google, te devuelve la friolera de ¡[9 resultados](https://www.google.es/search?source=hp&q=%22el%20pinflas%22)! De estos, 3 se corresponden con esta pregunta y sus clones. Otros se refieren a apodos. Solo dos textos parecen encajar:

> 1. Decidle que lo vais a denunciar a delitos telemáticos y poned la dirección de la web, veréis qué pronto deja de hacer el pinflas.
> 2. Ya veo por qué siempre cogen a los fugitivos, se ponen a hacer el pinflas en las casas.

Con solamente estos dos ejemplos escritos, yo diría que equivale a *hacer el [chorra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8zu2YZ1)*, o incluso a *hacer el [capullo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7MxWvWZ)* si la frase va más dirigida como insulto.

Si buscas solamente "pinflas" ya se encuentran más resultados. Uno interesante es:

> [...] o pensaban que eras un "pinflas" -un gañán, vamos- [...].

La palabra *gañán* significa literalmente "hombre fuerte y rudo", pero en La Mancha se usa también de forma despectiva como sinónimo de "hombre tonto" o "de pocas luces". Por tanto, "hacer el gañán" equivale a "hacer tonterías", y expresiones como "no me seas gañán" significan "no seas tonto".

No he podido encontrar más datos, así que no puedo decirte de dónde viene o dónde se usa (una pista podría ser la equiparación de *pinflas* con *gañán*, palabra muy manchega aunque popularizada por algunos programas de televisión), si bien es cierto que, como dice [un comentario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23118/qu%C3%A9-es-hacer-el-pinflas#comment39156_23118), la palabra se parece sospechosamente al verbo *rempampinflar*, que no aparece en el DLE pero sí en un par de fichas del Fichero General<sup>1,2</sup> como corrupción de *[refanfinflar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Vc1rD9q)*.

> **refanfinflársela** una cosa o una persona a alguien
>
> 1. loc. verb. malson. coloq. Esp. Serle completamente indiferente. *Me la refanfinfla cualquier problema suyo.*

Si así fuera, la expresión adquiriría otro significado: *hacer el pinflas* sería "hacer ver que algo no te importa" (ejemplo 1) o "actuar como si nada importara" (ejemplo 2). O incluso "hacer cosas sin importancia" como en el ejemplo de tu pregunta.

---

<sup>1</sup> Diccionario de argot español, Víctor León. 1980.
<sup>2</sup> Diccionario de argot, Juan Manuel Oliver. 1986.

Comment: Buscando solo **pinflas** aparecen algunos resultados más, uno lo usa como sinónimo de gañan:  _«o pensaban que eras un "pinflas" -un gañán, vamos-»_. En otros casos no queda tan claro pero también podría ser, como aquí: _«Felipe el Hermoso, un pinflas.»_  o aquí: _«Para que las mujeres hablen lo mejor es callarse, no hablar en su nombre. No seas pinflas!»_

Comment: @blonfu "gañán" para mí es una palabra muy manchega. Literalmente significa "hombre fuerto y rudo", aunque se suele usar como insulto en el sentido de "persona de pocas luces". "Hacer el gañán" sería pues equivalente a "hacer tonterías". Amplío la respuesta con esta información.